# RxJava: How to .zip two Observable, then .merge them and eventually .reduce to aggregate all results

Tags: java, rx-java

I have the following code:

```
public void foo() {
    Long[] gData = new Long[] { 1L, 2L };

    rx.Observable.from(gData)
    .concatMap(data -> {

        rx.Observable<GmObject> depositObs1 = depositToUserBalance(data, 1);
        rx.Observable<GmObject> depositObs2 = depositToUserBalance(data, 2);


        return rx.Observable.zip(depositObs1, depositObs2, (depositObj1, depositObj2) -> {

            depositObj1.putNumber("seat_index", data);
            depositObj2.putNumber("seat_index", data);

            return rx.Observable.merge(
                    rx.Observable.just(depositObj1),
                    rx.Observable.just(depositObj2));
        })
    })
    .reduce(new ArrayList<Long>(), (payoutArr, payoutObj) -> {

        int seatIndex = ((GmObject) payoutObj).getNumber("seat_index").intValue();
        long payout = ((GmObject) payoutObj).getNumber("payout").longValue();
        payoutArr.add(seatIndex, payout);
        return payoutArr;
    })
    .subscribe(results -> {
        System.out.println(results);
    });
}
```

This code uses .zip to emits to observables, and then it adds a 'seat_index' property and calls .merge in order to use .reduce so eventually all results would be aggregated into an ArrayList.

There is a problem with this code: When .reduce processes its input it gets it as Observable and not as GmObject ...What function can 'extract' the GmObject from its Observable wrap?

Does it make sense to use rxJava this way? or there is a better technique?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `zip` operator take as third argument a lambda. this lambda is a 2 args function which return an object that result of the composition of args. And not a `Observable` of the result of the composition (but, of course, the object can be an `Observable`, but it's not what you want in your case).

So after your `zip` call, you'll have an `Observable<Observable<GmObject>>` but you expect an `Observable<GmObject>`.

I don't think that the `zip` operator is the operator you're looking for.

```
public void foo() {
    Long[] gData = new Long[] { 1L, 2L };

    rx.Observable.from(gData)
    .concatMap(data -> {

        rx.Observable<GmObject> depositObs1 = depositToUserBalance(data, 1).doOnNext(obj -> obj.putNumber("seat_index", data));
        rx.Observable<GmObject> depositObs2 = depositToUserBalance(data, 2).doOnNext(obj -> obj.putNumber("seat_index", data));


        return rx.Observable.merge(depositObs1, depositObs2);
    })
   .reduce(new ArrayList<Long>(), (payoutArr, payoutObj) -> {

        int seatIndex = ((GmObject) payoutObj).getNumber("seat_index").intValue();
        long payout = ((GmObject) payoutObj).getNumber("payout").longValue();
        payoutArr.add(seatIndex, payout);
        return payoutArr;
   })
   .subscribe(results -> System.out.println(results));
}
```

Comment: So simple and yet I couldn't figure it out myself....I've never used doOnNext()...

Comment: @dwursteisen Any way to do this on Android (without lambda)?

Comment: replace lambda with anonymous class. (try on a Java 8 project and ask your IDE to transform it to an Anonymous class to see what I meen)